# Default Document not appending query string properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, iis, iis-7

I want to be able to append query string on the default document and re-direct with the query string (append).

[www.example.com/?test=1](http://www.example.com/?test=1) [FAILS]

it takes me to a 404 page not found. Now the issue is that all other pages will append the query string:

[www.example.com/about?text=1](http://www.example.com/about?text=1)  [WORKS]

How can I append query string on default document?

I was able to partially fix for fb's query string:

```
<rule name="fb Query String" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^fbclid=" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
```

When applied this rule will re-direct:

[www.example.com/?fbclid=IwAR3FhQ23wiLYsMUl5Mk-CYo_X74nw4-0MVPCpTt20V_KoVtizkOtBGP7TIg](http://www.example.com/?fbclid=IwAR3FhQ23wiLYsMUl5Mk-CYo_X74nw4-0MVPCpTt20V_KoVtizkOtBGP7TIg)

to

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

when I set `appendQueryString="true"` I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and I also want to match for just the default document page not all URLs as the rule states above: `<match url="(.*)" />`  Do I match for home.aspx or do I match on the .com because it's the default document?

Comment: We will need a [mcve].

Comment: I am thinking a URL re-write rule in web.config could do the trick or also maybe try using global.ascx with LINQ or stringbuilder.

Comment: Sounds great. Feel free to share what you have tried.

Comment: will do. am just trying to figure this out first.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules You explicitly wrote a rule to infinitely redirect if `appendQueryString="true"`, and FRT can prove that clearly. What exactly did you want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to append query string on the default document and re-direct with the query string (append). I am not good at iis rules, and that's part of the reason why i posted.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it seems you have already implemented redirect the url

from
`www.example.com/anytext/anytext?fbclid=1`
to
`www.example.com/?fbclid=1`

But the redirect rule also works with other urls which contain more path like `www.example.com/about`. So you tried with the redirect rule `fb Query String` which you provided above.

In my opinion, you just need to change `{R:0}` to `{QUERY_STRING}` and still set `appendQueryString` with false like below:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^fbclid=" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then it can implement your requirement.

If I misunderstood your requirements, please let me know.

Comment: thanks for the help.  upon further investigation i have found (for me) that the issue was stemming from a 404 page on gloabl.ascx.cs.  Thanks to @Hury Shen for the answer.  I am not the best at IIS rules, so again thanks.  I did test and it worked!